# Atribuir propriedade de cinco em cinco elementos

Tags: css

Tenho uma galeria que irá repetir, a cada cinco fotos, ele pula pra baixo.

Só que, quando o elemento for o quinto, ou seja =5, quero que aplique um `margin-right=0`.
Meu HTML:

```
<ul class="galeria">
  <li></li>
  <li></li>
  <li></li>
  <li></li>
  <li></li>
</ul>
```

Meu CSS:

```
.galeria li:first-child + li + li + li + li + li {
    margin-right: 0!important;
}
```

Ok, isso está funcionando perfeitamente, mas e quando for o elemento 10, 15, 20?
Não gostaria de ter que colocar uma `,` no meu CSS e repetir a propriedade, tem uma forma mais fácil? existe soma pra isso? que funcione pro **IE8**

Answer (score 3, accepted):

> Considerando sua edição: no IE8 não existe solução em CSS puro. Você terá de engessar o número de itens de lista nas suas regras, ou usar JavaScript. Abaixo, solução em CSS para browsers modernos.

Para isso você usa a pseudo-classe `nth-child`:

```
.galeria :nth-child(5n) {
    margin-right: 0 !important;
}
```

Um exemplo mais simples de visualizar (usando `<ol>` e alterado a cor a cada 5 itens):

```css
.galeria :nth-child(5n) {
    color: red;
}
```

```html
<ol class="galeria">
  <li></li>
  <li></li>
  <li></li>
  <li></li>
  <li></li>
  <li></li>
  <li></li>
  <li></li>
  <li></li>
  <li></li>
  <li></li>
  <li></li>
  <li></li>
  <li></li>
  <li></li>
  <li></li>
  <li></li>
  <li></li>
  <li></li>
  <li></li>
  <li></li>
  <li></li>
  <li></li>
  <li></li>
  <li></li>
  <li></li>
  <li></li>
  <li></li>
  <li></li>
  <li></li>
  <li></li>
  <li></li>
  <li></li>
  <li></li>
  <li></li>
</ol>
```

Comment: Usei o `+li +li +li` ao invés do `nth-child` por causa do IE8

Answer (score 1):

Olá, basta fazer do modo abaixo que vai ter o que deseja.

```
.galeria li:nth-child(5n) {
    margin-right: 0!important;
}
```

Para IE8, você pode utilizar JQUERY

```
$('.galeria li:nth-child(5n)').addClass('semMargem');

.semMargem{ margin-right: 0!important; }
```

Comment: Só que o `nth-child` não roda muito bem no IE8, por isso usei daquela forma.